# WooCommerce, Страница магазина, WordPress, Интернет магазин

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, назначение "Страница Магазина" в разделе товары, которая создается по-умолчанию. Возможно ли её как то отключить и как она может влиять на сам магазин? Может ли как то отразиться на сео, если с ней что то сделать? Просто для чего мне витрина (Страница Магазина), когда можно уже на определенную категорию перейти с главного меню? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Витрина магазина. Указывается в настройке: WooCommerce -> Настройки -> Товары -> Страница Магазина.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages/#what-is-the-shop-page

Ее можно удалить - удаление ничего не сломает.

Если где-то в коде использовалось получение адреса страницы магазина - вида wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ); - то буде вести просто на главную страницу.

Фильтр кнопки возврата в магазин

```
function change_return_shop_url() {
    return home_url();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'change_return_shop_url' );
```

https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Хорошо, а я могу создать этот каталог и просто убрать в ноуИндекс, и кнопку с корзины, которая  "Вернуться в магазин" просто удалить?

Comment: @АндрейКороль добавил в ответ фильтр, который заменяет ссылку возврата в магазин на главную страницу

Comment: Хорошо, а я вот когда добавлю фильтр, которй заменяет ссылку возврата, я могу саму "Страницу Магазина" (архивную страницу) добавить в ноуИндекс и НоуФоллов и тогда по идеи всё работать должно, правильно? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @АндрейКороль да. будет работать

Comment: Вообще-то это НЕ архивная, а самая что ни на есть настоящая страница. (а архивные в принципе удалить невозможно).

Comment: @SeVlad фактически она является архивной страницей для woocommerce - The Shop page is a placeholder for a post type archive for products https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages/#what-is-the-shop-page

Comment: В этом чтиве ты пропустил ключевое слово "placeholder" Сама страница - *не* архивная тк создаётся в админке (тип контента - page).  Архивные страницы - это вирт. страницы такие как рубрик, дат, авторов и тп А то, что в неё вставляется шоркод (который уже выводит архивную сущность) - это совершено другая история.  Так вот, эту страницу можно удалить физически. В отличии от архивных.

Comment: @SeVlad архивные тоже можно отключить. в register_post_type есть параметр has_archive (true/false)

Comment: 1. отключить !=удалить. #тыжпрограммист ;) 2.has_archive  вообще про другое. 3. Да и вообще register_post_type никаким боком к архивным. Архивные - это таксономии (register_taxonomy). Кури маны.

Comment: @SeVlad что за дичь? с каких пор архив = таксономия? register_post_type определяет наличие у него архива.

Comment: О... дичь пошла..  С таких, с каких появилась иерархия шаблонов https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png "Archive Page" хорошо видно? А "Singular Page"? Или не понятно что это такое?

Comment: @SeVlad ты пишешь дичь. на твоем скриншоте хорошо видно, что "custom_post_type_archive" != "custom_taxonomy_archive". они по разному инициализируются, у них разная иерархия шаблонов. писать, что "Да и вообще register_post_type никаким боком к архивным. Архивные - это таксономии" - это дичь

Comment: @SeVlad что тебе вообще не нравится в моем ответе? даже функция is_shop - определяет страница архива типа поста product как true . https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/is_shop

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120221/discussion-between-sevlad-and-valerii-vasiliev).

Answer (score 0):

> Может ли как то отразиться на сео, если с ней что то сделать? Просто
> для чего мне витрина (Страница Магазина), когда можно уже на
> определенную категорию перейти с главного меню?

Эта страница может быть полезна в том случае, если у вас главная страница продвигается по запросам вида "название_компании", "название_компании официальный сайт...",
а вам также нужен трафик по запросам вида "название_компании интернет-магазин". Вот под эту группу запросов и удобно затачивать "Страницу Магазина".

Comment: Но я ведь так понимаю она необходима для того, что бы сам WooCommerce понимал что у меня за товары и откуда их брать, не так ли? Но я ведь не могу же весь каталог у себя на главной странице выставить или в чём суть

Comment: Андрей, выше писали, что можно и без этой страницы. Она нужна если хотите показывать на одной странице все категории и подкатегории, а также - по несколько товаров в каждой категории (последнее - опционально).
Вместо этого можно, например, вывести ссылки на категории товаров в меню.
 А если хотите вывести кое-какие категории / подкатегории на главной (или любой другой), воспользуйтесь шорт-кодами, их у Woocommerce много.
Также можно в настройках Ву выбрать именно главную в качестве «страницы магазина» - тогда всё это отобразится на ней.